# SSH and Ping to hosts concurrently with Python asyncio?

Tags: ssh, python-asyncio, ping, paramiko

I'm trying to SSH/Ping to hosts concurrently, but I don't see any result so for, probably my implementation isn't correct. This is what I have so far. Any idea appreciated.

```
import paramiko
import time
import asyncio
import subprocess

async def sshTest(ipaddress,deviceUsername,devicePassword,sshPort): #finalDict
    try:
            print("Performing SSH Connection to the device")

            client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

            client.connect(ipaddress, username=deviceUsername, password=devicePassword, port=sshPort, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
            print("Channel established")     

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)       

async def pingf(ip):
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c','5', ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = p1.communicate()[0]
    print(output)

async def main():
    taskA = loop.create_task(sshTest('192.168.255.68','admin','admin','22'))
    taskB = loop.create_task(sshTest('192.168.254.108','admin','admin','22'))
    taskC = loop.create_task(sshTest('192.168.249.134','admin','admin','22'))
    taskD = loop.create_task(sshTest('192.168.254.108','admin','admin','22'))
    task1 = loop.create_task(pingf('192.168.255.68'))
    task2 = loop.create_task(pingf('192.168.254.108'))
    task3 = loop.create_task(pingf('192.168.249.134'))
    task4 = loop.create_task(pingf('192.168.254.108'))
    await asyncio.wait([taskA,taskB,taskC,taskD,task1,task2,task3,task4]) 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    end = time.time()
    print("The time of execution of above program is :", end-start)
```

Comment: The above code won't run -- you're referring to a variable `loop` but you're not creating it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asyncio is a form of [cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking). This means that in order for tasks to run concurrently, a task must *explicitly yield control* back to the scheduler, which in Python means "your tasks need to `await` on something".

Neither of your tasks ever calls `await`, so they're not going to run concurrently. What you have right now is going to run serially.

If you want to run `ssh` connections concurrently, you're going to have to either:

- Replace `paramiko` with something like [AsyncSSH](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is written to work with `asyncio`, or
- Use threading or multiprocessing to parallelize your tasks, rather than using `asyncio`.

Additionally, if you're working with `asyncio`, anything that involves running an external command (such as your `pingf` task) is going to need to use `asyncio`'s [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) method.

---

For the example you've shown here, I would suggest instead using the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module. Your code might end up looking something like this (I've modified the code to run in my test environment and given the `sshTest` task something to do beyond simply connecting):

```
import concurrent.futures

import paramiko
import asyncio
import subprocess


def sshTest(ipaddress, deviceUsername, devicePassword, sshPort):  # finalDict
    try:
        print("Performing SSH Connection to the device")

        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        client.connect(
            ipaddress,
            username=deviceUsername,
            password=devicePassword,
            port=sshPort,
            look_for_keys=True,
            allow_agent=True,
        )
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("sh -c 'sleep 2; uptime'")
        output = stdout.read()
        return output
    except Exception:
        return "failed to connect"


def pingf(ip):
    output = subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-c", "5", ip])
    return output


def main():
    futures = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        futures.append(pool.submit(sshTest, "localhost", "root", "admin", "2200"))
        futures.append(pool.submit(sshTest, "localhost", "root", "admin", "2201"))
        futures.append(pool.submit(sshTest, "localhost", "root", "admin", "2202"))
        futures.append(pool.submit(pingf, "192.168.1.1"))
        futures.append(pool.submit(pingf, "192.168.1.5"))
        futures.append(pool.submit(pingf, "192.168.1.254"))

    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        print("return value from task:", future.result())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is there an option to distinguished between the output of each host when debugging, when run in concurrent?

Comment: Sure. You can return the hostname along with the output (e.g. `return (ip, output)`).

Comment: what are the available options in python to parse this logging data to collect or display only specific pieces of data from it? which library should I look into?

Comment: I think you might want to open a new question for that: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, and comments are really the best place for this discussion. You're not really generating much logging data in this example. You could just use the standard `re` library to extract data from the `ping` result, for example.